# Using the transform effect on an adjustment layer in premiere pro renders differently from timeline view

Tags: premiere, rendering

I'm working on a video where I use an adjustment layer to zoom in and position multiple clips at once. This is what my timeline and preview look like in premiere pro:

[image]

Note the position of the serum application in the preview view.

now here is the same moment from the rendered video show using vlc media player (black bars on the side aren't part of the video):

[image]

you can see everything in the background has moved over to the right, note the position of the serum application with regards to the facecam. I've been using the transform effect for a long time like this and only recently this started happening. I do tend to copy over the zoom layer from one project to another to save time.

What is going on here? how do I fix this?